# is $g$ is a harmonic?harmonic polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ be a real valued harmonic function on $\mathbb{C}$ and

$$g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},~~~~~g(x,y)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} u(e^{i\theta}(x+iy))\sin\theta d\theta$$

Then is $g$ is a harmonic?harmonic polynomial? Could any one help me how to proceed?Thank you.

Comment: Differentiate under the integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Differentiation under the integral gives
$$\Delta g(x,y) = \int_0^{2\pi}e^{2i\theta}\sin(\theta)[u''(e^{i\theta}(x+iy)) - u''(e^{i\theta}(x+iy))]d\theta = 0$$
Thus $g$ is harmonic.

Comment: How do you see whether it is a polynomial or not??

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam Not in general. If it were a polynomial in $x$ and $y$, then differentiating it e.g. with respect to $x$ a finite number of times should give us zero, but this is not true for any $u$.